# Cannot use a Silverlight 2 theme for Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight

I've tried to use a nice theme which Nikhil Kothari provides here http://www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-Themes.aspx. I downloaded his sample and simply added some styles to my app.xaml. But I got lots of errors saying 'ContentPresenter doesn't have FontFamily' blah blah blah.

I'm using SL4, and apparently Nikhil's sample was made for SL2. Is that so I got the compilation errors? Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance, 
yokyo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, that is why you are getting the errors. Silverlight has undergone quite a few changes since version 2. One of those is that the ContentPresenter control no longer has a FontFamily property. If you absolutely must use that theme you will have to find all references to ContentPresenter in app.xaml and remove the FontFamily properties. After that you will no doubt get other errors, and you will just have to do the same with them. But that is a lot of work and there is no guarantee that it will work 100%. I would recommend that you find and use some other theme instead, something that is built for SL 4.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. I was thinking that I cannot use that theme, and have already tried to fix the theme as you mentioned, but it's pretty tough work, so it's very sad though, it's time to give up using that nice theme. Thanks! yokyo